# How to create a simpler proper Exception Handler message for "Error converting data type varchar to bigint" on textbox's value if it's not number?

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server

In my C# (webform), i have implemented a sql query.
The UPC field (varchar type) only contains numbers.
My textboxUPC.Text is passed into this UPC field in SQL of my SELECT query.

i.e.

```
SELECT UPC
WHERE (convert(bigint, UPC) BETWEEN '2529300168' AND '5529300168')
```

If letters are inputted in the textboxUPC instead of numbers, then this error will occur:
[image]

Can I just use some if statement maybe in JavaScript that says
IF textboxUPC.Text is not number,
Then a popup message alerts the user have to enter only numbers?

Comment: Simply, Yes you can do. you can use `isNan()` function of JavaScript.

Comment: How to do it if want to set it up in c# instead of in JavaScript?

Comment: Use `long.TryParse` in your web form to see if the TextBox has `bigint` (Int64/long) value. Only pass it to your query if `long.TryParse` returns true.

Comment: I have written the JS and C# methods in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ID="upc" value=" " />
```

**JS:**

```
  function func() {
  var upc = document.getElementById('upc').value;
  if (isNaN(upc)) {
  alert("Invalid");
  return false;
  }
  else{
  return true;
  }
  }
```

If you want to check it in code behind C# use `Try Parse`:

```
string Str = textBoxUPC.Text;
long Num;
bool isNum = long.TryParse(Str, out Num);
if (isNum)
{
 //your code here...
}
else
{
//display error here...
}
```

Comment: Just a minor suggestion, `BigInt` maps to `long/Int64` so use `long.TryParse` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write your own Javascript validation, then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric) might be useful. Client side validation is great for building a more responsive application, but you should always validate input on the server side also.

ASP.NET webforms provides a quick way to do both with the built in validation controls. [Here is a great resource for learning how to use the built in validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx).  You might be able to use a regular expression validator similar to this:

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Numbers Only" Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="group">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never trust the user input blindly and akways do validation checks before using it anywhere.

Use `Integer.TryParse` , or `Long.TryParse` to check whether the text in textbox is a nnumber or not, and convert to numeric type. Show a message if this function returns False, otherwise continue with executing your query.